# Scanner InputMismatchException error when trying to read boolean input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have the Java code below with a `readFile()` method that I've implemented with a `Scanner` to read a file line by line and separate into five different objects, but when it gets to the `boolean` input it throws an `InputMismatchException` error.  What's causing this error?  I've tried a few different things, I just added the `usedelimiter(",")` to the scanner which has caused this error, but before using the delimiter, it wasn't closing the `Scanner`.  What am I doing wrong?

My file data looks like this:

```
Chevy, Malibu, 1999, 10000, true,
Ford, Focus, 2001, 5000, false,
Porshe, Carrera, 1995, 35000, true,
Honda, Insight, 2014, 18000, true,
Hyundai, Elantra, 1998, 9000, true,
end
```

and my method looks like this:

```
//scan the identified file to separate the different data streams
while(scCars.hasNextLine()){
    index++;
    scCars.useDelimiter(", ");

    if(scCars.hasNext()){
        //pull out the first string and set it as this car's make
        make = scCars.next();
            c.setMake(make);              

        //pull out the second string and set it as this car's model    
        model = scCars.next();
            c.setModel(model);

        //pull out the first int and set it as this car's year    
        year = scCars.nextInt();
            c.setYear(year);

        //pull out the first double and set it as this car's price    
        price = scCars.nextDouble();
            c.setPrice(price);

        //pull out the first boolean and set it as this car's happy    
        happy = scCars.nextBoolean();
            c.setHappy(happy);
        }
        //add them all to the arraylist as this car object    
        c.carList.add(new CarA(c.getMake(), c.getModel(), c.getYear(), c.getPrice(), c.getHappy()));            
    }
    scCars.close();                    
}
```

Here's the full stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextBoolean(Scanner.java:1782)
at cara.CarGui.readFile(CarGui.java:256)
at cara.CarGui$1.actionPerformed(CarGui.java:191)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Post a complete example reproducing the problem, along with the input file, and the stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the first line of your file:

> Chevy, Malibu, 1999, 10000, true,

As you can see, the very last character is: `,`.
Now let's look at your delimiter: `scCars.useDelimiter(", ");`. As you can see it expects a comma *and* a whitespace. So, we know that the last comma on each line of your file is *not* a valid delimiter. Therefore, the scanner will read `true,` (or `false,`) instead of `true` (or `false`).

To fix that, change your delimiter to `scCars.useDelimiter(",\\s*");` to accept a comma and any amount of whitespaces. You could also use `scCars.useDelimiter(",\\s?");` if you don't want to split on a text with more more than one whitespace.

Btw: you have another problem: you don't handle the last file line *"end"* correctly, but this is another question.

Comment: Correct. The last character sequence of each line in his file is  ",\n"  which fails to match to ", "

Answer (score 1):

This happening because last part in each line just have `,` not `,<whitespace>`, which you have specified in your scanner delimiter. I would suggest you to make the following changes.

```
scCars.useDelimiter(",");

make = scCars.next().trim();
model = scCars.next().trim();
year = Integer.parseInt(scCars.next().trim());
price = Double.parseDouble(scCars.next().trim());
happy = Boolean.parseBoolean(scCars.next().trim());
```

**OR**

you can use the `regex` for handling it. The regex for handling zero or more white space is `,\\s*` along with one comma. Then you need to make only one chage to your delimiter.

```
scCars.useDelimiter(",\\s*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem of your data set format and your delimiter.

You can just remove the spaces after ',' and use

```
sc. useDelimiter(',');
```

Just make sure that whatever delimiter you are using, the separated values are of exact format which are expected by the type you are asking from Scanner

e.g.

```
sc.nextInt() must have an int to return
sc.nextBoolean() must have a boolean to return
```

In your case **sc.nextBoolean()** is **Not** working because next value is **'true,'** which is not a valid boolean